# Can not add a column to existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table viz. expenses with three columns as under

```
ExpenseId int NOT NULL,
ExpenseName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Invalid bit NOT NULL
```

To add a new column (`OldCode char(4) not null`), I used design feature for tables in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. But I get following error

> 'Expenses' table
>   - Unable to modify table. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OldCode', table 'TransportSystemMaster.dbo.Tmp_Expenses'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Incidentally I have been able to add same column with same specifications to other tables of the same database.

Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Table Consist of Existing Records

and you are pushing a new column of type `NOT NULL`.

so for older records the data have to be something.

try something like this

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD Column_name INT NULL
GO
UPDATE MY_TABLE <set valid not null values for your column>
GO
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ALTER COLUMN Column_name INT NOT NULL
 GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `OldCode` is `NOT NULL`, you should specify a default value for it.

Answer (score 3):

when you have some rows on your table you can't add a column that is not nullable you should provide a default value for it

```
Alter Table table_name add OldCode int not null DEFAULT(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify values for all the 4 fields of the table, its purely because, while designing the table you set the definition of the columns to be not null. Again you are adding a new column called OldCode and setting to be not null, all ready existing records hasn't got a value. So that is the reason its complains